# javascript id vs. class selector nested

Tags: javascript

If I have following code

```
<div id="container1">
   <div id="elementcontainer1" class="elementType"></div>
</div>
<div id="container2">
   <div id="elementcontainer2" class="elementType"></div>
</div>
```

To find element that belongs to specific container, I can select first correct container and then inside it correct type by class:

```
document.getElementById(containerId).getElementsByClassName("elementType")
```

or alternatively I can specify in the element which container it belongs to:

```
document.getElementById("element" + containerId)
```

The latter would be faster as it goes straight to the right id, but on the other hand I'd need to define different id for each although the components are otherwise the same.

What aspects I should consider when choosing which one to use?

Comment: First of all you should consider that the speed difference will most likely be absolutely negligible for most use cases.

Comment: `document.getElementById("elementType" + containerId)` won't work since it only accepts an ID, not a class. Maybe you're think of `querySelector`?

Comment: If you know your Ids you can access directly

Comment: @j08691 it was a typo.

Comment: @JorgeMejia I can't do for example document.getElementById("element2"), because then I'd need a new function for every element.

Comment: A typo? It's still incorrect with `document.getElementById("element" + containerId)`. `getElementById` takes an ID, nothing more.

Comment: @j08691 he/she can access the element by this, as the id of the div is "elementContainer1" what if containerId consists of a string with the value of "Container1" so the whole line would become document.getElementById("elementContainer1");

Comment: @j08691 plus (+) is a mathematical sign that takes two elements and puts them together. Therefore, when containerId = container1, that means "element" + containerId = elementcontainer1, which is the id of the div.

Comment: @Boat Thanks for clarifying the plus concatenator. I only have the gold badge in the JavaScript tag and 150K rep and hadn't heard about it before.

Comment: @j08691 happy to help ;) funny mistakes are funny, no less with a golden badge :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, think about how much are you gonna be using that and on how large DOM. Cause if you put like 100k elements in DOM it's gonna lag from rendering no matter your selectors. For example, if it's gonna be done once or twice and only bring lag of around 1-5 X 100ms it's not all that important. If by comparison you are going to use it on every filter change and you expect users to reconfigure filters every couple of seconds and faster then lag will matter.

Other than that I believe you could pick whichever you have the least time invested. If you can be positive 1st won't be broken by future upgrades go with it.

On the other hand, if you got an easy way of enumerating each end every one of them with unique id I would always prefer to target directly, faster, easier to debug, less likely to become broken with updates.

TL DR: **unique Id if it's not a massive time to invest in doing so, otherwise the other method.**

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar issue and i used the latter code. Because i knew the ID's of the elements i was using.

The back end logic would iterate and print all the rows also with buttons attached to the row with the value/id as same as the row.

So i used the code

```
document.getElementById("elementContainer" + containerId);
```

As i knew the indexing of the elements.

If that isn't your case, you can use the LOC

```
document.getElementById(containerId).getElementsByClassName("elementType")
```

To access your elements, it would really be upto you which code do you want to use. Meanwhile, the speed difference would almost be negligible for most use cases, as @CBroe stated in the comments.

Comment: well, my question was about what aspects I should consider rather than which one _I_ should use, so it's not really opinion based.